# Any app for iOS that let me store files protected by password

Tags: ios, security, iphone-app

I'm searching for an app that let me store documents, pdfs or whatever protected by password/code.

I don't want any network function like sync across device, password managers, service/web accounts needed or anything like that.

I just want to keep files, like docs, pdf, txt on local storage. If it is possible, app will delete data after N failed passcode attempts.

The app mustn't be free of charge. But not too much expensive, if is possible.

Is there any app with this requisites?

Thaks a lot! ; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after a lot of time searching, I found an app that fit with my requesites.

The winner app is: [iDiscrete](https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/idiscrete/id370574724?mt=8)

It is an app developed for old iPhones. It needs iOS 4.0+.

The app costing €2.99 and this are its features:

- File types supported: JPG, PNG, BMP, GIF, 3GP, ASF, AVI, DIVX, DV, FLV, GXF, M2P, M2TS, M2V, M4V, MKV, MOOV, MOV, MP4, MPEG, MPEG1, MPEG2, MPEG4, MPG, MPV, MT2S, MTS, MXF, OGM, OGV, PS, QT, RM, RMVB, TS, VOB, WEBM, WM, WMV, TXT, DOC, DOCX, RTF, XLS, XLSX, PPT, PPTX, PDF and MP3
- WiFi Hard Drive: It support a HTTP server for transfer files between iPhone and PC/Mac

I finally choose this one, knowing that is an old one and doesn't support full screen on iPhone 6, 6+, 6s and 6s+ because it comes with no password manager, in-app purchase and don't need web registration.

The app is like a folder in the iPhone, protected by password and nothing more. Super simple. I don't need more.

I know that other app have more functions but I don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

**Folder Lock
By NewSoftwares.net**

seems to be your best bet.

[Here is the link](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/folder-lock/id372925917?mt=8)

The app is free however it has an **in-app purchase** costing $3.99 to get "Unlocked Feature Pack"
I haven't personally tried the app but, here is a quote of **some** of its features:

> • Lock Folder
>  • Protect private photos
>  • Hide sensitive videos
>   and pictures
>  • Password-protect secret audios
>  • Lock down
>   important documents
>  • Write secure notes
>  • Record voice
>   recordings and memos secretly
>  • Import Saved Contacts
>  • Lock
>   Videos
>  • Lock Photos
>  • Create secret Contact Groups
>  • Send
>   multiple SMS to secret Contacts Groups
>  • Secure Browser (leaves no
>   traces and privacy enabled)
>  • Audio Import
>  • Save Protected
>   Wallet Cards
>   - Credit Cards
>   - Bank Accounts
>   - ID / Social Security
>   - Driver’s License details
>   - Business Cards
>   - Business Info
>   - Health and Hygiene
>   - Passport details
>   - General Purpose Cards